# BBCODE, preg_replace and double quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode, quote

```
preg_replace('/\[quote\=(.*?);(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/ms', '<blockquote>Posted by: \1 at \2.<br/>\3</blockquote>', $text);
```

This is what I use to replace the `[quote=user;id]content[/quote]` bbcode. Anyway, it works fine only, if there is one quote in post.

If I got:

```
[quote=user1;1] [quote=user0;0]some content here[/quote]

this is my reply to user0 post[/quote]
```

It'll replace only first quote, other will be just not replaced by the `<blockquote>`.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tested, repaired version

```
<?php
$out = '[quote=user1;1] [quote=user0;0]some content here[/quote]this is my reply to user0 post[/quote]';
$cnt = 1;
while($cnt != 0){
    $out = preg_replace('/\[quote\=(.*?);(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/ms', '<blockquote>Posted by: \1 at \2.<br/>\3</blockquote>', $out, -1, $cnt);
}
echo $out;
```

http://codepad.org/3PoxBeQ5

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try in a minute.

Comment: When I use this I get an error message: `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/public_html/[...]`

Comment: in fact, I don't know how to realize if yes or not. you can try various valid/invalid BBCode, inside html,css,php, then every special character to test if it works. And also depends on what you do think by `safe`

Comment: By safe I meant that if it won't "lag" server in case if there are many quotes.