# Need regex to grep quote tags

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace, bbcode

I need regex for preg_replace to change:

`[quote](content)[/quote]` into `<blockquote>(content)</blockquote>`

+

`[quote=(username)][/quote]` into `<blockquote>Post user: (username)</blockquote>`

+

`[quote=(username);(id)][/quote]` into `<blockquote>Post user: (username).<br/>ID: (id)</blockquote>`

Ofcourse, the (content), (username), (id) should be the ones which regex will grep.
I've searched alot, and didn't finded any good regex for this action. So, help me guys, please.

Comment: You should check this out first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/488963/best-way-to-parse-bbcode

Comment: possible duplicate of [BBCODE, preg_replace and double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632325/bbcode-preg-replace-and-double-quotes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it with 3 separate regexes, since it would turn into a giant mess if you tried to put two conditionals inside one regex.

```
preg_replace('#\[quote\](.+?)\[/quote\]#', '<blockquote>$1</blockquote>', $input);
preg_replace('#\[quote=(.+?)\]\[/quote\]#', '<blockquote>Post user: $1</blockquote>', $input);
preg_replace('#\[quote=(.+?);(.+?)\]\[/quote\]#', '<blockquote>Post user: $1.<br\>ID: $2</blockquote>', $input);
```

This is taking your question verbatim, of course. It seems like you forgot about the (content) in the second two examples.

**EDIT:** If you really want to use only one `preg_replace` call, you can make arrays containing those patterns and replacements, as seen in the second example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

**EDIT 2:** Does BBCode support nested quote blocks? If so, this would be a bit more complicated.

**EDIT 3:** Even simpler way. Since `[/quote]` always leads to `</blockquote>`, you can skip all this capture group nonsense, and just replace the open and close tags separately:

```
preg_replace('#\[quote\]#', '<blockquote>', $input);
preg_replace('#\[quote=(.+?)\]#', '<blockquote>Post user: $1>', $input);
preg_replace('#\[quote=(.+?);(.+?)\]#', '<blockquote>Post user: $1.<br\>ID: $2', $input);
preg_replace('#\[/quote\]#', '</blockquote>', $input);
```

Comment: Please look at my actual regexes: http://pastebin.com/L2sJWMYR

... look at this also please! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638527/preg-replace-bbcode-quote-tags-overlapp

Comment: If you want to parse nested quote blocks, it can be done, it'll just be more painful. Try replacing the `(.+?)` content capture group with this:
`(.*?(?:\[quote.+?\[/quote\])*.*?)`

Comment: Getting such warnings now: `Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 48 in /home[...]` this is what I got : http://pastebin.com/PV1zvDpu , please , help me.

Comment: Sorry, I was tired. I've replaced it fine now. It doesn't throws up an warning, but also it doesn't bring any good results - I can not see any changes between: `(.*?(?:\[quote.+?\[/quote\])*.*?)` and `(.*?)`. I explained more, in what cases it fails etc, here: http://pastebin.com/snYMXFFY . Here is my actual code: http://pastebin.com/Q700vP1Q . And what did you mean saying I've got extra parentheses? I can't find one. Maybe a little tip? Because I'm in stuck with this for over 2 days now. :/

Comment: Yeah, I thought of a better way to do the nesting. Since you're running this in a loop anyway, let's try just adding a negative assertion group, so it will *only* match the innermost quote block each time. Try this for the content: `((?:(?![quote).)*)`. That will match as many characters as possible that do not contain a [quote] tag, thus the match will fail for any quote block that is not innermost.

Comment: Oh, and you have a bug in your code. You are returning `$cnt` with each preg_replace, so it is getting blown away every time. You need to use a separate variable and add the three `$cnt`s

Comment: Still the same + it now don't replace the [quote] tags. My actual code: http://pastebin.com/K1MM1x1T

Comment: My bad, you need to escape the `[` and `]` characters in there.

Comment: I did. Here is the actual output: http://pastebin.com/DwpD78sR
As you can see, not all of the quotes are replacing by preg_replace. 
I've also updated the code with all of your tips, you can see the actual code in here: http://pastebin.com/1ezifsVX

Comment: Your `while` loop should be `||`s, not `&&`s.

Comment: Also, when I said "escape" I meant change them to `\]` and `\[`, not remove them

Comment: It looks better, but still broken.

Comment: It just occurred to me that since `[/quote]` always gets replaced by `</blockquote>`, you could simplify this a lot. Instead of doing this complex capture group, just replace the open and close [quote] tags separately. Editing my answer now...

Comment: Aight thanks, I've accepted the answer for now. I'll test your edited code in a minute . Thank you again bro!